# Missing font color in some input(s)

Tags: bug, user-interface, design

I'm using the dark system theme with light foreground and I've noticed, that, in some inputs, background color is set, but font color is missing. So, I'm getting the light-colored text on white background, and that's quite unreadable.

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Post a link to your theme and I'll take a look.

Comment: @BenCollins It's not a Firefox theme, but a colors in gtk and qt styles.
gtkrc: http://pastebin.com/uFbn6KgM

Comment: which distro are you using? does it only appear in the tags editor or have you noticed elsewhere?

Comment: @m0sa Arch Linux, but I don't think, that problem is in it. It also appears in searchbox, but reverse: font-color is set to black, and input background is missing - so, it became default, dark background-color.